# Construction of a compact set with 3 limit points

Tags: general-topology

This problem is asked in this website, but I have some confusion about it still. I need to construct a compact set with exactly 3 limit points

the set $A={\frac{1}{n}}: n\in \Bbb Z$ has only one limit point, $0$. My question is why $1$ is not a limit point? I am confused. And what should I do to add up the limit points in general?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Your observation is correct. I think you are supposed to consider points which are "strict" limit points, in the sense that they are limits of *other* points. These are sometimes called (I think) *condensation* points, or *accumulation* points.

Comment: @MVP I really really dont understand you :) what do you mean by "limits of other points? I know that accumulation point is another name for limit point, but I dont know in which sense they are different. Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: $1$ is not an accumulation point because it is not a limit of points "other than $1$", right? The only sequences which converge to $1$ are eventually constant: $\ldots, 1,1,1,\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just shift the set and take a union

so eg
$\{ 1/n\} \cup \{ 1+ 1/n \} \cup
\{2 + 2/n\}$

Answer (score 1):

For $1$ is not a limit point, the ball $B(1,1/4)$ does not contain points in $A$ other than $1$ itself.

Comment: Incorrect. $1\in A$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Accepting that, how can I add up further limit points to the compact set? Is there any method of doing that in general?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at the set you suggested, together with the union of a couple of translates of that set. (What if you also had sequences approaching 1, and 2?)

Comment: What is a translate of a set?

Comment: Can I do like $k+1/n$? Would that work?

Comment: Yes. A "translate" is just a shift by a fixed amount.